# Install rubygems on production machine (closed down network)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, rubygems

I am a noob to Ruby and R-o-R and have been tinkering around deploying the app that I have built.

The production machine where I need to deploy my app is a fresh machine and hence needs the gems to be installed on it. I have been trying to install the gems by copying the gems that I need from my remote machine to the prod box. So I have got question or two around that

1. Is there a better way of installing rubygems on a machine behind a firewall?
2. Once I have all the gems installed on the prod box, which is the best way to deploy the app itself? Do I need to set up some sort of rsync/scp etc? Or is there a better industry standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage both problems with [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano). Capistrano is a ruby script that allows you to deploy your project from your working copy, or directly from a remote repository. It is done through a SSH connection.

It deals also with the gems by using Bundler. If some of your gems are private (in a Github account for instance), you can setup Capistrano to use your local SSH keys (`ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true`). Another way is to use the Capistrano recipe [Strategy Copy Bundled](https://github.com/rudionrails/capistrano-strategy-copy-bundled) to bundle locally your gems before uploading them on your remote server.

As summary, with Capistrano, it is possible to setup a deployment where your local machine is an intermediary where everything (your app, your gems, ...) goes through.

```
|------------|       |----------------|           |--------------|
|  Internet  |-------|  Your Machine  |---[SSH]---|  Production  |
|  (Github,  |       |----------------|           |--------------|
|   RubyGems,|
|   etc.)    |
|------------|
```

**Update**
I've added below an example of `config/deploy.rb` doing what you want. But it's far beyond your question to explain you all details of capistrano. I advice you to read about it, I've put some references with you can start.

```
require 'capistrano-strategy-copy-bundled'

set :application, "your application name" # name of the application

set :user, "deployer"  # The server's user for deploys
default_run_options[:pty] = true # Must be set for the password prompt
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true } # Using SSH forward agent

set :repository, "git@github.com:account/repo.git"
set :scm, :git # type of scm used
set :deploy_via, :copy_bundled # Capistrano clones your git repo to /tmp on your
                       # local machine, tars & zips the result, and then
                       # transfers it to the server via sftp.

set :copy_dir, "/tmp/#{application}" # path where files are temporarily
                                     # put before sending them to the
                                     # servers
set :copy_exclude,  ".git*" # excluding the .git directory

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/" # Where to deploy on the server
```

References:

- https://help.github.com/articles/deploying-with-capistrano
- https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Getting-Started
- https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-From-The-Beginning
- https://github.com/rudionrails/capistrano-strategy-copy-bundled

Comment: Will try this out. So far from the description capistrano seems to be doing what a auto-deploy script/job would do. If it is as it seems, this should help solve the issue. Thanks for the diagram. Looks deliciously simple now.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work out of the box. It looks like one of the methods is missing.

Comment: @JNovice I've updated my answer with an example. There is a lot of details to set up a deployment with Capistrano, I cannot cover all of them. Hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to copy the gems from local to production machine. There is a `gemfile` in your application that installs all the required gems for your project.

So all you need is to do `bundle install` from your project path at prod to install the gems at production machine.

Once you do `bundle install` at prod, you can run the server there, like you normally do at local.

To be more clear, if you are doing `rails server` at local, then in order to install the gems and then to run the server at production-

```
bundle install
rails server -e production
```

**NOTE:** Don't forget to do other changes that are specific to the production like changing your `database.yml` settings.

Comment: If things were only that rosy. bundle install traces back to rubygems.org which requires outbound as well as inbound network access. In most cases prod boxes have a tight firewall access conditions around them that restricts such stuff.